# PHP - Splitting a string with two parameters

Tags: php, regex, explode

I'm trying to split a string received from a $_GET in PHP, but I'm stuck, as it's more than the explode() function will handle - or so I think.

If the string I receive contains quotations marks (""), I want the split (by spaces) to keep the stuff in quotation marks intact. E.g. A result like 'Foo bar "Bar 2"' would be split into 1 --> Foo ; 2 --> bar ; 3 --> Bar 2 .

I've looked through explode(), preg_split, and similar things, but I don't understand how to split a larger string by space, whilst keeping intact substrings that are in quotation marks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the definition of a CSV file with space as the delimiter. Use the CSV parsing function [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

```
$str = 'Foo bar "Bar 2"';
$arr = str_getcsv($str, ' ');
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => Bar 2
)
```

For PHP < 5.3, from the PHP manual's comments:

```
if (!function_exists('str_getcsv')) {
    function str_getcsv($input, $delimiter = ",", $enclosure = '"', $escape = "\\") {
        $fiveMBs = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        $fp = fopen("php://temp/maxmemory:$fiveMBs", 'r+');
        fputs($fp, $input);
        rewind($fp);

        $data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, $delimiter, $enclosure); //  $escape only got added in 5.3.0

        fclose($fp);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm on a PHP version that's lower than 5.3 (I'm getting the undefined function error), and I'm not in a position to upgrade it. How would I go about getting the same result of this function, without using it as you have illustrated?

Comment: I have amended my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting what I think is an encoding problem, but I'm not sure. If, when using the $_GET, I input something with quotes, e.g. "Foo 3", my result is Array ( [0] => \"Foo [1] => 3\" ), when it should be Array ( [0] => \"Foo 3\" )? Do I have to fix my $_GET result or the "function str_getcsv($input, ..." part?

Comment: Are the slashes in the input? If so, you probably have "magic quotes" turned on (a relic of old, dirty PHP disabled in modern versions) and need to strip those slashes.

Comment: Checked the output a different way... and yup, slashes were messing it up, which stripslashes() fixed. Thank you very much for all your help.